# Select Random Files From Txt File and Save to Another Txt - VBScript

Tags: select, random, vbscript

I have a text file with 350.000+ lines. I need to select 100 random lines from that file and save them to a separate text file.

1. Is this possible with vbscript?
2. The file is UTF-8 will this be an issue?

I may need to do something more complex after this like: Select 100 random lines and save them to a text file from multiple text files (each containing 350k+ lines). Will this be achievable as well?

Comment: What have you tried? Most languages have a random function, and vbscript can read text files. Is there a particular reason for vbscript? generally questions follow the format here is the programming problem ive got, here are the things ive tried, help. It would be good to attempt at least

Comment: vbscript is required because it will be run by another software which can only execute vbscripts. I admit that I may had to put more input into my question, but I'm not very good with vbscript and since it's a simple language I wanted to know if it's even possible to do such a thing first before I dive in into research. I won't ask questions in this format again, I promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Randomise
    Randomize 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            .AddNew
            .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
        .Sort = "RandomNumber"
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Randomises lines in a file.

```
Sub Cut
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        LineCount = 0
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            LineCount = LineCount + 1
            .AddNew
            .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop

        .Sort = "LineNumber ASC"

        If LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
            If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
                .filter = "LineNumber < " & LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
            ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
                .filter = "LineNumber > " & LCase(Arg(3))
            End If
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "b" then
            If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
                .filter = "LineNumber > " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3))
            ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
                .filter = "LineNumber < " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
            End If
        End If

        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Can chop top 100 lines from a file.

---

```
Cut
filter cut {t|b} {i|x} NumOfLines

Cuts the number of lines from the top or bottom of file.

t - top of the file
b - bottom of the file
i - include n lines
x - exclude n lines
Example



filter cut t i 5 <"%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

---

```
---

Random
filter random
filter rand
Randomises lines of text in a file. Used to unsort a list.

Example

filter random < "%windir%\win.ini"
```

These are samples from another program. Common declarations are

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
```

General use is

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
cscript filter <inputfile >outputfile
cscript filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | cscript filter >outputfile
other_command | cscript filter | other_command
```

t

Comment: Thank you so much for these provided samples! This makes things so much easier! Getting onto work now..

Answer (score 0):

This is the batch file I use to call the above functions. The batchfile installs itself into the path if needed. This allows the vbs script (filter.vbs) to be used in a command prompt as if it's an exe file.

```
@echo off


Rem Make sure filter.vbs exists
set filter=
set filterpath=
Call :FindFilter filter.vbs

Rem Add filter.bat to the path if not in there, setx fails if it's already there
setx path %~dp0;%path% 1>nul 2>nul




Rem Test for some command line parameters
If not "%1"=="" goto main

echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo   Filter.bat

echo   ==========
echo.
echo     The Filter program is a vbs file for searching, replacing, extracting, and 
echo     trimming console output and text files.
echo.
echo     Filter.bat makes Filter.vbs easily usable from the command line. It 
echo     controls unicode/ansi support and debugging.
echo.
echo           Type Filter Help or Filter HTMLHelp for more information.
echo.
cscript //nologo "%filter%" menu
Goto :EOF

:Main


echo %date% %time% %~n0 %* >>"%~dp0\FilterHistory.txt"



rem echo Batch file ran
rem echo %*
Rem /ud Unicode and Debug
If %1==/ud FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO cscript "%filter%
" //nologo //u //x %%j&Goto :EOF

Rem /u Unicode
If %1==/u FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO cscript "%filter%
" //nologo //u %%j&Goto :EOF

Rem /d Ansi Debug
If %1==/d FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO cscript "%filter%
" //nologo //x %%j&Goto :EOF

Rem -ud Unicode and Debug
If %1==-ud FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO cscript "%filter%
" //nologo //u //x %%j&Goto :EOF

Rem /u Unicode
If %1==-u FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO cscript "%filter%
" //nologo //u %%j&Goto :EOF

Rem -d Ansi Debug
If %1==-d FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%*") DO cscript "%filter%
" //nologo //x %%j&Goto :EOF

Rem ANSI
cscript "%filter%
" //nologo %*&Goto :EOF

Goto :EOF

:FindFilter

If Exist "%~dpn0.vbs" set filter=%~dpn0.vbs&set filterpath=%~dp0&goto :EOF

echo find filter 1
If Not "%~dpnx$PATH:1" == "" set filter=%~dpnx1&set filterpath=%~dp1&goto :EOF

echo find filter 2
If Exist "%temp%\filter.vbs" set filter=%temp%\filter.vbs&set filterpath=%temp%&goto :EOF

copy "%~dpnx0" "%~dpn0.bak"
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo creating "%~dpn0.vbs"
    goto :EOF
)

copy "%~dpnx0" "%temp%\filter.bak" 

echo Error %errorlevel%
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo creating "%temp%\filter.bak"
    Goto :EOF
)
Goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like this:

```
randomize  
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set numberDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  
set objInFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Mega\Desktop\250kWords.txt", 1, true, 0)  
set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Mega\Desktop\100WordsSelected.txt", 2, true, 0)  

strLines = objInFile.ReadAll  
arrLines = split(strLines, vbNewLine)  
intUpperLimit = ubound(arrLines)  
numPicks = 100 

'number of random picks must be less than or
'equal to the number of lines in the input file
if intUpperLimit < numPicks then  
    numPicks = intUpperLimit  
end if  

Do Until numberDic.Count = numPicks  
    index = int(rnd() * intUpperLimit) + 1  
    intRandom = arrLines(index)  
    intRandom = Trim(intRandom)  
      'if blank lines exist in text file, don't add them
    if intRandom <> "" then  
          'if the line chosen is not in the dictionary object, add it
        if not numberDic.exists(intRandom) then  
            numberDic.Add intRandom, intRandom  
        end if  
    end if  
Loop  

for each item in numberDic  
    objOutFile.WriteLine item  
next  

objInFile.close  
objOutFile.close
```